# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase mexicana "no mames"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, coloquialismos, méxico, interjecciones

Estoy interesado en saber el significado literal original de la expresión "no mames" o de dónde vino.

Escuché la frase en vídeos del terremoto en México, en los cuales la usaban como una interjección. Estoy preguntando el origen de la frase y no su significado, el cual ya lo sé.

Comment: A mí sinceramente me recuerda a la expresión española "No seas mamón", forma vulgar de decir "no te solaces (en el mal de los demás)", "no disfrutes (haciendo sufrir a otras personas)"

Answer (score 4):

En http://diccionario.sensagent.com/mames/es-es/ encontré:

> mamar v intr (Se conjuga como amar) I 1 Chupar la cría con la boca la leche de su madre 2 Dar de mamar Amamantar a la cría una hembra 3 tr Adquirir una persona desde su muy temprana infancia cierta educación, ciertos hábitos, ciertas cualidades: mamar el gusto por la música, mamar el gusto por la política II (Groser) 1 Emborracharse una persona 2 Chupar con la boca los órganos genitales de una persona: mamar la verga, mamar la panocha 3 No mamar No decir o hacer cosas imprudentes o absurdas: «No mames, pinche Héctor, estás diciendo mentiras», «No mamen ¿cómo van a construir un muro de metal de 3000 km de largo?».
>
> Sinónimos: beber, chupar, embeber, fregar, huevear, joder, molestar, potar, sorber, tomar, tomarse

La definición de FGSUZ no es la única.  Para entender la acepción relacionada con la leche materna, imagina que eres el hermano mayor del nenito que se cae, llora, y quiere calmarse con lechita de Mamá, entonces quizás dirías, "Ay, no mames," es decir, "No te portes como bebé, aguántatelo."  De ahí los sinónimos *fregar, joder, molestar*.

Siempre que alguien percibe algo fuertísimo, súbito e increíble, va a expresar su incredulidad con algo corto y fuerte, por ejemplo, en inglés, "Fuck this [shit]", "God damn it" o "Jesus H. Christ" se pueden usar para expresar "No puedo creer que esta cosa tan horrible me esté pasando."  **Tiene que ser una expresión corta** para satisfacer esta necesidad.  "Is this for real?" o "You've got to be kidding" funcionarían en general pero creo que son demasiadas sílabas para un gran temblor.

Otro sitio que corrobora la idea "no te portes como bebé" [[1](https://culturacolectiva.com/historia/chido-orale-wey-y-el-origen-de-las-palabras-favoritas-de-los-mexicanos/)]:

> Directamente de las calles del Distrito Federal, significaba que no actuaran como un bebé. Al principio a esta expresión le seguía una que decía “no mamo, tomo chichi con popote”. Televisa popularizó la frase con un pequeño cambio, en lugar de decir no mames comenzaron a decir no manches para apelar a las clases bajas.

Los ejemplos de Flxtr son buenísimos.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, todo apunta al origen obvio, bastante relacionado con el significado literal. En este caso el verbo mamar, se sobreentiende, hace referencia no a las ubres humanas sino más bien al órgano sexual masculino. Lo que básicamente es una felación dicho de forma soez. De hecho, en México suele acompañarse de ese mismo objeto directo, que es como "vega" pero con una r en medio.

Comment: ¿Y los mexicanos, en un terremoto, llaman ¡no mames!? No entiendo el porqué.

Comment: El origen ya pasaría a un segundo plano, la expresión se convierte en una interjección más. En muchos otros sitios decimos "No jodas" (con perdón).

Comment: @mdewey En un terremoto se diria "no mames" porque se ve una desgracia o una a punto de pasar, ejemplo: un fan de un equipo de futbol lo diria varias veces en una jugada en la que su equipo pudiera salir con gol en contra, si se anota aveces se  dice una vez mas "no mames" pero con una emocion diferente, Por eso se dice varias veces antes y despues de un accidente por varias personas.
La entonacion y emocion de las palabras da el significado al "no mames". Incluso la "no mames" es sinónima de varias frases que se usan como insultos. XD

Answer (score -2):

El origen , aún que suene ilógico, viene de el inglés "no man, just" si se pronuncia en forma correcta este sonara exacto a "no manches" de este modo tenemos muchos anglicismos, qué naturalmente adaptamos al español, imagina la escena, un estadounidense diciéndole a un mexicano que no hiciera algo de cierta manera (por qué lo estaba haciendo mal) su diálogo sería "no, man! Just..." Lo que sonaría en su cabeza como "no manches", cómo esas canciones en inglés que se "washashean" se palabrerean, y así muchas personas entenderán "all right, I think we´re gonna make it” se trasformó en (all right) “pingüino Rodríguez"

Comment: ¡Interesante!  Entiendo cómo llegamos de "I think we're go" a "pingüino" pero ¿cómo llegamos de "na make it" a "Rodríguez"?